# Deleting Firestore Document when ID is set to a name which is not pre-defined anywhere

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore

Currently, I have a database of users. Each document ID is set to the users initial-name upon singing up, however, this username may have changed overtime, but the document name does not.

My question is, how do i grab a document by the name, and delete it?

I tried using

```
"db.collection('Users').where('user_id', '==', this.user.uid)"
```

which I use elsewhere to match the auth to user profile elsewhere but am unsure as to how I would delete the entire document as ".delete()" straight after throws errors.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update following your comment below (explaining that actually `this.user.uid` is not the id of the Firestore document)**

So you should indeed execute a query and when you get the result of this query (in the `then()` method), delete the (unique) document returned by the query, as follows:

```
var query = db.collection('Users').where('user_id', '==', this.user.uid);

query.get()
.then(function(querySnapshot) {
    var docSnapshot = querySnapshot.docs[0];   // We get the first (and unique) document of the querySnapshot
    docSnapshot.ref.delete();
});
```

---

You don't need to use a [Query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.Query) for that (using [`where()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.CollectionReference#where) defines a Query).

You can just point to the document (i.e. define a [`DocumentReference`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentReference)) and call the [`delete()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentReference#delete) method, as follows.

```
db.collection('Users').doc(this.user.uid).delete();
```

Comment: Ah ok i see, and i would first define "this.user" with "firebase.auth().currentUser" ?

Comment: "I would first define `this.user` with `firebase.auth().currentUser` -> Yes that would be perfect. Or you could use the `onAuthStateChanged` listener to set the user id in a Vuex store. See this tutorial for more detail: https://savvyapps.com/blog/definitive-guide-building-web-app-vuejs-firebase

Comment: Ah yes thank you! I actually started the project with VUEX but disabled for now, as it was confusing me, but that tutorial ius exactly what I needed to continue with it!

I guess for now ill use no-vuex then go back and update the app with it.

Thanks! :)

Comment: Glad i could help you! Just note that in this tutorial there is an a error at the following lines  https://github.com/savvyapps/SAVuegram/blob/168e1a47002642a6c97b073c52214f3daa38349e/src/components/Login.vue#L126-L127 because the `signInWithEmailAndPassword` method returns a `UserCredential`, not a `User`.

Comment: Just gave it a try and it seems to not be working. I guess it is because the Authentication ID doesnt match the document UID (as the document uses the users username instead) so, it has no way to refer to the "current" user. 

Unless I am misunderstanding?